# How do I reindent all my codes in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide, clojure

In most of the IDEs, I had a Reindent All command. How do I do that in Eclipse 1.2?

Edit: The commands work with Java codes but is there a way I can get it to work with Clojure?

Comment: Eclipse 1.2? Seriously?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

will format all your code according to active formatting rules, this includes any indentation rules you defined (tabs/spaces, amount of those, etc...)

You can change those rules at:

- Window > Preferences
- Java > Code Style > Formatter

Comment: I think you have to consult the clojure plugin provider ;) clojure-dev has formatting on the roadmap but not yet implemented

Comment: This is a suboptimal solution for me. I do want consistent indentation on all project files, but I don't necessarily want consistent spacing between operators (e.g. `v + dv` vs `i+1`). A global format forces everything to be consistent.

Answer (score 10):

Is **CRTL+SHIFT+F** working in eclipse 1.2 ? 
In 3.5 is working fine.

You can also select all the code you want to indent, and then hit **CTRL + I**

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse is up to version 3.5 now. You **might** want to upgrade.

To format your code however you like, including indentation and a dozen other minute details that you might care about, you can set Formatter options (under Preferences / Java / Code Style / Formatter). You can also tell Eclipse to run the Formatter on every save, along with other rules.

Answer (score 1):

**TAB** and **SHIFT+TAB** should also work for selected lines of code/text - provided your tab character is configured to be equal to your indent space count.